# glide doesn't skip cache

Tags: android, marker, android-glide

I am using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library for create marker for Google map.

```
Glide.with(context)
                    .load(filepath)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform(context, poi, selectedCatId))
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            Log.d(MapsFragment.TAG, "resource ready");
                            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(new LatLng(poi.getLat(), poi.getLng()))
                                    .title(poi.getTitle())
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource)));
                            map.put(marker, poi);
                        }
                    });
```

When 2 different objects have the same image and own marker color, method transform() not invoked. I think, this is due to that Glide cached images. How to fix it?

Comment: Post your CircleTransform code. It can be an issue with getId() method.

Comment: solved!! .signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))